# sort filtered gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I have a filtered gridview in an updatepanel. I want to allow to sort filtered data. How can this be done? When I click to sort a column it reloads the entire gridview.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[How Sorting Works in the GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875.aspx)

> The  GridView control does not perform
>   its own sorting of columns, but rather
>   relies on the data source control to
>   perform sorting on its behalf. ...see rest of article

Comment: I guess I must be dense, because I'm still having problems.

I can sort.

I can filter.

I cannot sort a filtered GridView without losing the filter.

If I try to reapply the filter to the SqlDataSource in the Sorting Event, I get an endless loop.

Help!